# How to get dynamic html with Selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-crawler

I'm trying to develop a web crawler in python that, given a website, analyzes its html and searches for all href tags, but with libraries like Beautiful Soap it is not possible to obtain the dynamic content of an html page, in fact the crawler I am making must also discover the hrefs generated by any script for example. So I discovered Selenium and made this script:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")
time.sleep(15)
html = driver.page_source
print("HTML :", html)
links = []
elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
for elem in elements:
    href = elem.get_attribute("href")
    links.append(href)
return links
```

But when I run it I don't find in the html the content that, for example with Chrome developer tools, I see, so my question is: how can I get the whole html of a page with also the html generated by a generic script?

URL TO TEST: "https://www.lubecreostorepratolapeligna.it/it/cucine-lube/cucine-moderne/"

Example of test: I want to take the href of an image of a kitchen present in the catalog

N.B. I don't want to select an element and wait for it thanks to WebDriverWait as I'm creating a generic crawler for any site so I don't have a particular element to wait or search for, I just want to get the dynamic content of a generic html.

If there are better libraries for my purpose please tell me.

UPDATE : i have found a solution to my problem here is the code to search for any iframe in the html (dynamic content of page) and then navigate them

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
browser.get(url_to_search_for)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
browser.close()
        
iframe = []
for x in soup.find_all('iframe'):
    print(x['src'])
    if str in x['src']:
        print('ciao')
        iframe.append(x['src'])
for x in iframe:
    try:
        page = urllib.request.urlopen(x, timeout=20)        
    except HTTPError as e:
        page = e.read()
            
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        print("HREF IFRAME", a['href'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The elements you are looking after is present inside an `iframe`.You need to switch to `iframe` first in order to get those elements.

```
url="https://www.lubecreostorepratolapeligna.it/it/cucine-lube/cucine-moderne/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.row iframe"))
time.sleep(5)
elements=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".ajax_content div.gb_CL_product>a")
links=[]
for elem in elements:
    href = elem.get_attribute("href")
    links.append(href)

print(links)
```

Please Note:- `time.sleep()` is a bad practice you should use `WebDriverWait()`

**Console Output:**

```
['https://www.cucinelube.it/it/cucine-moderne/adele-project/', 'https://www.cucinelube.it/it/cucine-moderne/clover/', 'https://www.cucinelube.it/it/cucine-moderne/creativa/', 'https://www.cucinelube.it/it/cucine-moderne/essenza/', 'https://www.cucinelube.it/it/cucine-moderne/gallery/', 'https://www.cucinelube.it/it/cucine-moderne/georgia/', 'https://www.cucinelube.it/it/cucine-moderne/immagina-plus/', 'https://www.cucinelube.it/it/cucine-moderne/luna/', 'https://www.cucinelube.it/it/cucine-moderne/noemi/', 'https://www.cucinelube.it/it/cucine-moderne/oltre/', 'https://www.cucinelube.it/it/cucine-moderne/round/', 'https://www.cucinelube.it/it/cucine-moderne/swing/']
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Your solution will be valid for any website or only in this particular website ? Because i need something that works for any website in input

Comment: Only the website you have posted.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to create a generic script that looks inside an iframe without specifying class names with the css selector?